# SwiftUI - ForEach with Stride

Tags: swiftui, ios13, xcode11

Im trying to create a list of Hstack'd cards, That is to say, I want to create a scroll view of a series of rows. Each row would contain an HStack of two views displayed side by side, and initialized by some list data structure.

```
struct MyHStackView: View { 

    var myArray = [SomeStruct(1), SomeStruct(3), SomeStruct(4), SomeStruct(5), SomeStruct(6)]

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) { 
            VStack { 
                ForEach(0..<self.myArray.count) { index in 
                    HStack { 
                        SubView(myArray[index])
                        SubView(myArray[index+1]) 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The only issue is my current implementation touches every element of the array, is there a `stride` function built into the new ForEach so that I can index on every other element on the array to initialize the row? How would you approach this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If just every other, you may try

```swift
VStack { 
    ForEach(0 ..< self.myArray.count/2) { index in 
        HStack { 
            SubView(myArray[index * 2])
            SubView(myArray[index * 2 + 1]) 
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you may need to use the `stride` function:

```swift
ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: self.myArray.count, by: 2)), id: \.self) { index in
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ah this is perfect! I didn't realize I could call the stride inside of the ForEach like that. Thanks!

Comment: As an experiment, I pasted this into a view: ```ForEach (Array(arrayLiteral: stride(from: 20, to: 50, by: 10)), id: \.self) {index in EmptyView()}``` (compiler required the arrayLiteral:), and now I get compile errors about  'ForEach' requires that 'StrideTo<Int>' conform to 'Hashable'. This appears to be equivalent to what's above - can you see where I went wrong?

Comment: @Feldur I can reproduce the error using your code, but the error disappears when I remove `arrayLiteral: `.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For simple use-cases the solution posted by E. Coms may work. If you plan on modifying or re-ordering the list, it may give you trouble since the id specified is the same as the index and List won't be able to correctly animate removals/additions/re-ordering.

I would create a data-structure to represent the tuple in an identifiable manner:

```
struct SomeStructTouple: Identifiable {
  let a: SomeStruct
  let b: SomeStruct

  var id: String {
    "\(a.id)-\(b.id)"
  }
}
```

and then create an array of touples to generate the list.