# SwiftUI get value of next loop in For Each

Tags: arrays, foreach, swiftui

I'm trying to display a value (the sum of 'timeMinutes') that have been entered on a date ('date'). I will display all of these entries in a ForEach loop. The idea is that I make a calculation on whether the new timeMinutes is higher or lower than the one entered on the last date.

Please note that date to time is a one-to-many relationship.

Making the ForEach loop is fine:

```
    ForEach(dates, id: \.self) { day in
        Section(header: Text("\(self.formatDate(date: day.date!))")) {
            ForEach(day.timeArray, id: \.self) { time in
                VStack {
                Text("\(String(time.timeMinutes))")
                }
            }
            Text("Total time is \(self.time.filter{$0.date.date == day.date}.map{$0.timeMinutes}.reduce(0, +))")
            Text("The last time you did this was: \(DATA FROM NEXT LOOP????)")
            Text("The difference is \(ADD/SUBSTRACT - RESULT)")
        }
    }
```

Basically I want the 'Total time is' from the next loop. How do I do this? My dates are sorted by date, so moving to the next set (a sort of Index +1-idea) should suffice. I've searched all over, but I'm breaking my head over how to do this.

And also how would that work out if I get to the last set? Does anybody have a suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to fix it :). Inspired by E.Coms ([SwiftUI - ForEach with Stride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548909/swiftui-foreach-with-stride)) I used the following method it.

```
        List{
           ForEach(0 ..< self.dates.count) { index in
                Section(header: Text("\(self.formatDate(date: self.dates[index].date!))")) {
                    ForEach(self.dates[index].timeArray, id: \.self) { time in
                        VStack {
                                 Text("\(String(time.timeMinutes))")
                         }
                    }
                    Text("Total time is \(self.values.filter{$0.date.date == self.dates[index].date}.map{$0.timeMinutes}.reduce(0, +))")

                    if index == (self.dates.count - 1) {
                        Text("No other values")
                    } else {
                        Text("Last month was: \(self.values.filter{$0.date.date == self.dates[index+1].date}.map{$0.timeMinutes}.reduce(0, +))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks to E.Com and others that might have had a think about this!